# Swagger not showing broken down array object - ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have the following C# ASP.Net Core Web API controller method for creating an "entity" using a POST:

```cs
[HttpPost("example")]
[SwaggerResponse(200,"Ok")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]MyModel create)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The model is defined as this:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
    public List<OtherProp> Other { get; set; }
}

public class OtherProp
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

When this is shown in swagger, you can see the "Other" property array looks like this:

[image]

Instead of the broken down model.  How do I get swagger to breakdown this model?

Comment: Did you found your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your are *missing the Swagger Decorator Attributes*, follow this below and replace the attributes with your specific `Types` / `MyModel`

---

Since you didn't put up your actual code, *to see how it works, use the default samples for e.g*. you can Install my Swashbuckle.Examples NuGet package. Decorate your methods with the new SwaggerResponseExample attributes below and you will see it work just fine!

```
// These attributes will help with your nested objects
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type=typeof(IEnumerable<Country>))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(CountryExamples))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<ErrorResource>))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string lang)
```

Also ensure you have it configured like so

```
configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
    })
    .EnableSwaggerUi();
```

Comment: These attributes decorate the swagger response - my problem is with the request model